# How to apply a tint on an image loaded from a bundle resource?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

On my iOS application, I am loading a bundled resource and I assign the image to an `UIImageView` like this:

```
UIImage uiImage;

if (m_viewModel.IsAvailableLocally)
    uiImage = UIImage.FromBundle("Downloaded");
else
    uiImage = UIImage.FromBundle("NotDownloaded");

uiImage.ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate);

m_imageView.TintColor = UIColor.White;
m_imageView.Image = uiImage;
```

The image is loaded and displayed correctly except for one thing. I am trying to apply a white tint on the `UIImageView` but the tint is not applied.

**Question**

How can I apply a tint on an image loaded from a bundle resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was not far off. The method `ImageWithRenderingMode` returns another instance of `UIImage`, as shown on the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/displaying-an-image?tabs=vsmac). This is the one that has the rendering mode properly set.

```
UIImage uiImage;

if (m_viewModel.IsAvailableLocally)
    uiImage = UIImage.FromBundle("Downloaded");
else
    uiImage = UIImage.FromBundle("NotDownloaded");

UIImage mutableImage = uiImage.ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate);

m_imageView.TintColor = UIColor.White;
m_imageView.Image = mutableImage;
```